# Neo4j: all paths between two entities (unclear performance)

Tags: performance, neo4j, path

I am using Neo4j Version: 2.3.3. I am trying to find all paths between two entities eg.,:

**(Edit)**

```
PathExpander<Object> expander =   Traversal.pathExpanderForAllTypes(Reldir);  
PathFinder<Path> finder = GraphAlgoFactory.allPaths(expander, depth); 
Iterator<Path> paths = finder.findAllPaths(first_node, second_node).iterator();

 while (paths.hasNext()) {

        Path path = paths.next();
            . . .
}
```

The result (example):

```
 "Entity: A"  "Number of paths: 16" "Longest path: 11" "Calculation: Time:  1.0 Millseconds" 
 "Entity: B"  "Number of paths: 1"   "Longest path: 3" "Calculation: Time:  2.6 Millseconds"
```

However, I have noticed that it is not always the case that the number of paths or the longest path play a role in the performance. For example:

```
   A-->b-->c-->D can be much faster than finding the path for A-->B
```

and also if the number of paths between A-->D is 10 can be much faster if the number of path between A-->D is only 4.
I expected that the number of paths and the path length will play a strong role in the performance.

Any explanation why such behaviour?

In contrast when I am interested to compute how many relationships are associated with one entity, I can see that there is dependences between the number of relationships and the computation time.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about your graph model? if you have a tiny graph and start up your test every time, the JVM warmup overhead will by far overshadow your algo-runtime.

Comment: My database contains 12 million entity and 31 millions of relationships. I am testing 61 entity pairs and try to find all paths between two entities. I run the test 10 times for each entity pairs. I also repeated the test many times in different days and the result always consistent.

Comment: It would be good if you could provide more example code. And perhaps use a path-expander that counts the number of hits in between. How many paths are returned from your iterator?

Comment: I edited my question. Please notice that this behaviour often appear for the tests 55 000 entities